# Paginate api graph results on android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-android-sdk

I get posts from several pages and show then in my app. I have a MAinActivity where I make the API call:

```
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Intent feed = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Feed.class);
                    feed.putExtra("response", response.getJSONObject().toString());
                    startActivity(feed);
                }
            }
    );
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("ids", sources);
    parameters.putString("fields", "posts{id,message,picture,object_id,properties,source,created_time},picture.width(150)");
    parameters.putString("locale", "es_ES");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

`sources` is a string with all ids concatenated ("id1,id2,id3...")

When I have the data I pass it to my `Feed` activity, where I handle it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.list_feed);
    PostAdapter adaptador;
    Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Post> arrayPosts = new ArrayList<>();
    String imgProfile;


    String JSONstring = inBundle.getString("response");
    try {
        JSONObject JSONfeed = new JSONObject(JSONstring);

        for (int index = 0; index < JSONfeed.names().length(); index++) {
            JSONObject pagina = JSONfeed.getJSONObject(JSONfeed.names().getString(index));
            JSONObject postsObject = pagina.getJSONObject("posts");
            JSONObject pictureObject = pagina.getJSONObject("picture");

           //{handle data and fields}

        }
        adaptador = new PostAdapter(this, arrayPosts);
        lv.setAdapter(adaptador);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The thing is this works fine but when I have a huge amount of data(now I have 25 sources), app crash without any error or log at the moment of the calling. I'm pretty sure the crash is for large data. When I delete some sources or put `limit(10)` on my call it works.

I need to know how to paginate this, I don't know if I did my code in a strange way but examples that I found are quite differents to mine.